# Porque a variável não está sendo atribuída na condição?

Tags: python, lista, variáveis, if, for

Estou tentando resolver o desafio 84 do Curso de Python do Curso em Vídeo que pede basicamente para fazermos uma lista com nome e peso, e indicar a pessoa com maior e com menor peso.

Estou escrevendo o código da mesma forma que já fiz anteriormente para definir os valores maiores e menores, porém na condição estabelecida somente é atribuído o valor na variável relacionada ao maior peso e não ao menor. E não estou entendo o porquê disso estar acontecendo.

```
pessoas = []
dados = []
r = ''
while r != 'N':
  dados.append(str(input('Nome: ')))
  dados.append(int(input('Peso: ')))
  pessoas.append(dados[:])
  dados.clear()
  r = str(input('Quer continuar? [S/N] ')).upper()
  if r not in 'sSnN':
    print('Resposta invalida, tente novamente.')
    r = str(input('Quer continuar? [S/N] ')).upper()

maiorpeso = menorpeso = 0
maiornome = menornome = ''
for p in pessoas:
  if p == 0:
    maiorpeso = p[1]
    menorpeso = p[1]
  else:
    if p[1] >= maiorpeso:
      maiorpeso = p[1]
      maiornome = p[0]
    if p[1] <= menorpeso:
      menorpeso = p[1]
      menornome = p[0]
print(f'Foram cadastradas um total de {len(pessoas)} pessoas')
print(f'Quem tem o maior peso é {maiornome} com {maiorpeso}kg e o menor é {menornome} com {menorpeso}kg')
```

Estou rodando o código no Google Colabs.
E a resposta do print final  mostra apenas o nome e o peso do maior, o nome do menor fica em branco e o peso fica 0.

Era para já na primeira condicional dentro do 'for', o peso menor ser atribuído com o mesmo valor do maior, e conforme fosse fazendo a leitura dos itens da lista, o peso menor fosse sendo atualizado quando encontrasse um valor menor.

Como comentei antes, está funcionado para o maior, mas não para o menor.

Comment: Sim, na primeira parte, quando acrescento os dados de nome e valor. Coloco pesos variados. O maior é identificado e atribuído na variável maior, porém o menor não, fica como 0 e não atribui nome. 
Como eu comentei acima, já fiz desse mesmo modo em outras situações e deu certo, porém nessa, em específico não está dando, a variável menor não está "captando" o menor valor encontrado na lista.

Comment: `p` é uma lista, logo `p == 0` nunca será verdadeiro e por isso não atualiza o menor peso, a menos que insira um peso negativo

Comment: Porque atualiza somente o maior? Não consegui entender isso. 
Porque o `p` eu coloquei como um contador para a lista pessoas, ou seja, na primeira contagem, `p==0` pegaria o valor da primeira pessoa da lista e atribuiria tanto ao maior quanto ao menor peso. Na próxima contagem do loop, ou seja, `p==1`, a segunda pessoa da lista seria analisada, então se o peso dela fosse maior iria substituir o maior anterior e se fosse menor, iria substituir o menor anterior, e assim sucessivamente. 
Mas só funciona com a variável `maiorpeso` e não menor. 
Teria alguma sugestão de correção?

Comment: Vamos supor que o `nome = a & peso = 5`, em p vai ter o valor `['a', 5]`

Comment: Legal que resolveu o problema, mas para as próximas questões é importante fornecer um [mcve] do seu código, de forma que a postagem sirva para a [finalidade do site](/help).

Comment: `input` retorna uma string, então usar `str` é desnecessário. E em vez de ficar criando cópias de `dados` e limpando toda hora, acho mais simples fazer assim: https://ideone.com/722FKn (veja também que usei uma forma mais pythônica de iterar pelos elementos, além de outra maneira de lidar com o maior e menor)

Comment: @hkotsubo entendi. Muito obrigada pela resposta. Gostei bastante da forma que fez. Já me ajudará em outras situações semelhantes.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
for p in pessoas:
    if p == 0:
        #...
    else:
        #...
```

Aqui você está definindo p como um valor de pessoas, o qual é um **Array de Arrays**, logo p será um array e por isso `p == 0 nunca será verdadeiro`

Para corrigir isso, podemos fazer algumas coisas tais como

1. Utilizar a função [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

   ```
   maiorpeso = menorpeso = 0
   maiornome = menornome = ''
   for l, p in enumerate(pessoas):
       if l == 0:
           maiorpeso = p[1]
           menorpeso = p[1]
       else:
           if p[1] >= maiorpeso:
               maiorpeso = p[1]
               maiornome = p[0]
           elif p[1] <= menorpeso:
               menorpeso = p[1]
               menornome = p[0]
   ```
2. Fazer uma validação se o peso inicial é igual a certo valor

   ```
   maiorpeso = menorpeso = None
   maiornome = menornome = ''
   for p in pessoas:
       if maiorpeso is None:
           maiorpeso = p[1]
           menorpeso = p[1]
       else:
           if p[1] >= maiorpeso:
               maiorpeso = p[1]
               maiornome = p[0]
           elif p[1] <= menorpeso:
               menorpeso = p[1]
               menornome = p[0]
   ```
3. Definir os pesos baseados nas informações da 1ª pessoa

   ```
   maiorpeso = menorpeso = pessoas[0][1]
   maiornome = menornome = pessoas[0][0]
   for p in pessoas[1:]:
       if p[1] >= maiorpeso:
           maiorpeso = p[1]
           maiornome = p[0]
       elif p[1] <= menorpeso:
           menorpeso = p[1]
           menornome = p[0]
   ```

Comment: Muito obrigada!
Agora consegui entender.
Usei a primeira opção que sugeriu utilizando o `enumerate()` e funcionou perfeitamente para o que precisava.

Comment: @RafaelaHenemann que bom que consegui ajudar, no início pode não ser tão intuitivo o motivo de algo não funcionar mas com o tempo vai pegando o jeito